# Countif using Offset

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm working with this code which Will help me to go over a group of columns depending on the date.

The thing is, I'm trying to make my file to check the frecuency of the values and count the values that "Cumplen".

I mean, if the values in cells(x,"c") are "Diarios" then count the quantity of "Cumple" in cells(x,"w").

I'm using offset function cuz it allows me to go over more than one column at a time.

Thanks.

```
Sub pruebaestadisticas()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Seguimiento").Rows(2).Cells

fila = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Seguimiento").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Seguimiento")

For x = 4 To fila

For Each c In r

        If c.Value = "3/1/2022" Then
        
        If .Cells(x, "C").Value = "Diario" Then
            
        c.Offset(fila - 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(c.Offset(x - 2, 1), c.Offset(x - 2, 1)), "Cumple")
        
        End If
        
        End If
        
    Next c

Next x

End With

End Sub


This is the same code in a direct way:


Sub pruebaestadisticas2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Seguimiento").Rows(2).Cells

fila = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Seguimiento").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Seguimiento").Range("W33").Value = ""

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Seguimiento")

For x = 4 To fila

For Each c In r

        If c.Value = "3/1/2022" Then
        
        If .Cells(x, "C").Value = "Diario" Then
            
        .Range("W33").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells(x, "W"), "Cumple")
        
        End If
        
        End If

Next c

Next x

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `fila - 1` doesn't change, which means the destination of all of these values from each loop is going into the same row. Is this intended?

Comment: `Range(Cell,Cell)` is used to create a multi-cell region spanning from one cell to the other. The idea is that you supply the top left corner and the bottom right corner. In your code, you put the same cell as both parts, making the resulting range the same single cell that you gave it.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and didnt work. In the way the code is made it works only with the last row. I mean, it does what I want but only with the last row.

Comment: You're looping "For each row in the used range of my worksheet and for each cell in row 2, perform the following:". You can see how this can quickly spiral out of control. If you have 16384 columns in your row, and a thousand rows in your worksheet, you're doing 16384000 iterations. VBA is not very fast, and this will take many minutes to complete.

Comment: I think you meant to do `fila - 5 + X` in your `c.Offset(fila - 1, 1).Value`

Comment: The loop is not a deal. I Will add exit for son.

Comment: I added the same code made directly, please check it

Comment: I don't understand what you're using `countif()` on a single cell when you can go column by column and `countif()` on the entire column.  Your `CountIf()` can include an `if` for "3/1/2022".

Comment: I need to make some filters. For that I need to count only the variables depending on their frecuency

Comment: I can go over the entire column. But the thing is I need to go over some cells in the column depending on the frecuency.

Comment: I figured it out at least!!!. It Was a matter of using count instead of countif and making some changes in the loop